# I am not getting the err property while I am giving a WRONG POST request. instead of giving the err property, my app is going to crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
    
    if(err){
        console.log(err);   
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: "USER doe's not exist"
        })
    }
    
    if (!user.authenticate(password)){
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: "password is wrong"
        })
    }
    
    var token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.SECRET);
    res.cookie("token", token, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000)});
    const { _id, name, email, role } = user;
    res.json({ token, user: { _id, name, email, role }});
})

//POST request that I am giving from postman application
{ 
  "email": "notavailable@gmail.com", //not available in database
  "password": "shubham@17" 
}
```

Why i am not getting the err property while I am giving a WRONG POST request. instead of giving the err property, my app is going to crash.

events.js:287
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticate' of null
    at C:\Users\Shubham Ghosh\Desktop\MERN\projBack\controller\auth.js:45:19
    at C:\Users\Shubham Ghosh\Desktop\MERN\projBack\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4846:16
    at C:\Users\Shubham Ghosh\Desktop\MERN\projBack\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4846:16
    at C:\Users\Shubham Ghosh\Desktop\MERN\projBack\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    at C:\Users\Shubham Ghosh\Desktop\MERN\projBack\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4869:21
    at C:\Users\Shubham Ghosh\Desktop\MERN\projBack\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4424:11
    at C:\Users\Shubham Ghosh\Desktop\MERN\projBack\node_modules\kareem\index.js:135:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at C:\Users\Shubham Ghosh\Desktop\MERN\projBack\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    at C:\Users\Shubham Ghosh\Desktop\MERN\projBack\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4869:21
    at C:\Users\Shubham Ghosh\Desktop\MERN\projBack\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4424:11
    at C:\Users\Shubham Ghosh\Desktop\MERN\projBack\node_modules\kareem\index.js:135:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at C:\Users\Shubham Ghosh\Desktop\MERN\projBack\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4848:13
    at C:\Users\Shubham Ghosh\Desktop\MERN\projBack\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to checking `err`, you also have to check `if (user)` to see if you actually got a `user` object back.  With that database, there is a middle ground where you didn't get an error, but no user was found either.  You need to check both of those conditions.  Or said another way, you get `err` when there's something wrong with the database.  You can `user === null` when there's nothing wrong with the database, but the query didn't find a matching user.  So, you can check for both of those like this:

```
User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
    
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);   
        return res.status(500).json({message: "database error"});
    }

    if(!user){
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: "USER does not exist"
        })
    }
    
    if (!user.authenticate(password)){
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: "password is wrong"
        })
    }
    
    var token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.SECRET);
    res.cookie("token", token, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000)});
    const { _id, name, email, role } = user;
    res.json({ token, user: { _id, name, email, role }});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this, it might help.

```
User.findOne({ email }, (user) => {
    
    if(!user){  
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: "USER doe's not exist"
        })
    }
    
    if (!user.authenticate(password)){
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: "password is wrong"
        })
    }
    
    var token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.SECRET);
    res.cookie("token", token, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000)});
    const { _id, name, email, role } = user;
    res.json({ token, user: { _id, name, email, role }});
})

//POST request that I am giving from postman application
{ 
  "email": "notavailable@gmail.com", //not available in database
  "password": "shubham@17" 
}
```

**I will suggest you to work with promises so you can handle the errors easily.
so you can do this, using promise to catch the err.: (you can see i did `.then(user => {//here the function if no errors}).catch(err=>console.log(err)`

```
User.findOne({ email }).then(user => {

    if (!user) {

        return res.status(400).json({
            message: "USER doe's not exist"
        })
    }

    if (!user.authenticate(password)) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: "password is wrong"
        })
    }

    var token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.SECRET);
    res.cookie("token", token, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000) });
    const { _id, name, email, role } = user;
    res.json({ token, user: { _id, name, email, role } });
}).catch(err => console.log(err))

//POST request that I am giving from postman application
{
    "email": "notavailable@gmail.com", //not available in database
        "password": "shubham@17"
}
```